# Data Driven testing

Tags: webdriver-io

I am currently working on deciding a tool for automation an app on react/redux platform.
Most of the scenarios that I have in the app is possible to automate using webdriver io.
There are certain test cases or scenarios which repeat itself for different data sets.
For eg. 
Steps to be executed:

1. Login to the application
2. Enter search criteria Step
3. Enter Color 1, Color 2, Color 3
4. Save and Validate

Test Data:

```
|UserName|Password|Search Criteria|Color 1|Color 2|Color 3|
|abc     |  abc   | search 1      |red    |       |       |      
|abc     |  abc   | search 1      |       |green  |       |  
|abc     |  abc   | search 2      |grey   |white  |       |
|abc     |  abc   | search 3      |white  |black  | yellow|
```

I have to execute the same set of code/steps multiple times depending the number of rows of test data we have.
I tried reading a lot of documentations but could not find any package which supports this type of automation in webdriver io.

Answer (score 0):

I've succesfully used the code in this package https://github.com/gburghardt/jasmine-data_driven_tests

it allows to write data driven tests using 2 functions **all & using**

Here is an example that you can find in the github page:

```
all("blank values are invalid",
    [
        "",
        null,
        undefined
    ],
    function(value) {
        expect(isEmpty(value)).toBe(true);
    }
);
```